# Unsafe seats on a Boeing 777?

Tags: air-travel, safety, seating, singapore-airlines

On a flight with Singapore airline from Zurich to Singapore with a Boeing 777 I had an aisle seat. Shortly before take off, a flight attendant approached me and told me that this seat is unsafe and I had to move seats for take off. I was given a seat that is normally used by the crew members. After take off I could go back to my first seat.

However, I felt a little bit uncomfortable after that for the rest of the flight. Who wants to sit on an unsafe seat?

So, what are the reasons that such a seat could be considered unsafe only during takeoff? What should I have done?

Comment: FYI, the seats used by crew members are called _Jump Seats_.

Comment: @HaLaBi Why are they called Jump Seats?

Comment: Because it can be folded I guess, check [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_seat).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's more likely that there was a problem with the seat.

This could be, but is not limited to (and I've seen all of these):

- malfunctioning/broken seatbelt.
- seat stuck in the reclined position.
- loose screw in seat
- broken component in seat support structure

As such, until they get a chance to service it, they move you.

Presumably because of the different stresses the plane goes under during acceleration, that they moved you.  If you seat broke mid-flight, you could stroll around and sit somewhere else.  If it happens during take-off, they can't even get up to help you (Well they shouldn't).

It's not like there's an "unsafe" seat on every flight - you don't have to try and remember to avoid say, 37A, or something. It's just that for that flight, they probably had a problem with one.

Comment: A weakened seat might be strong enough to sit on, but liable to break up under the stress of a crash. Crashes basically only happen at takeoff and landing (or those that don't aren't survivable anyway) so it makes sense to move you at those times.

Comment: I think if it was a broken seatbelt, the seat would have been folded in as you can't use it during flight (what if the there is turbulence or the seat belt sign is illuminated?) So I would argue on seat stuck on the reclined position.